# How to make a Persistent connection over GPRS mobile network?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I would like to set-up a persistent `tcp connection`

for eg. with `redis or mqtt or socket.io`.

My only concern is the reliability of the connection on GPRS mobile network.

I am looking for libraries / methods to implement a client to one of these (or other servers) which can deliver and receive data without loss. I am not concerned about latency , but the data I intend to send either direction must reach without a problem.

The client will be implemented on android 2.2

Comment: It would be great to accept an answer to reward the best answer. :) just a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQTT provides quality of service levels that guarantee message transmission using a message handshake. If the connection fails for whatever reason, the client library will retry the message delivery once the connection has returned.

- QoS level 0 indicates that the message will be received by the server at most once.
- QoS level 1 indicates that the message will be received by the server at least once.
- QoS level 2 indicates that the message will be received by the server exactly once.

You would require QoS > 0, and to check that the implementation correctly recovered in the case of a disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Here are some infos that might help you

- [infos about TCP -> Reliable transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission)
- [Some Snippets for TCP
  Connection](http://www.anddev.org/socket_programming-t325.html)

Answer (score 0):

TCP does some basic consistency check for you. [But it's only a 32 bit CRC](http://www.androidsnippets.com/create-a-md5-hash-and-dump-as-a-hex-string) so your combination of sensitive data and unreliable network (GPRS or other) means that you must implement your own additional verification scheme. I think that [MD5 hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is enough for you, so besides your data, send also a 16 byte of MD5 fingerprint. Google will tell you stories about how MD5 is old, weak, obsolete etc. and at least SHA-1  is a must. Which is true but in context of cryptography. You don't aim for security i suppose, you only need an integrity check, for which MD5 is absolutely fine and has an advantage of being much faster than anything else.